# Trying to make BeforeDoubleClick change row colour between rows B:S and insert date in A

Tags: vba, excel

Beginner here!
I have concocted this code from various sources of the internet and am trying to put it together to work harmoniously together with no success. Any comments would be greatly appreciated :)

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object,ByValTarget As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Target.Column > 1 And Target.Column < 20 Then
If Target.Interior.Color = vbWhite Then
Sh.Rows(Target.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 162, 200)
ElseIf Target.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 162, 200) Then
Sh.Rows(Target.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 203)
ElseIf Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 203) Then
Sh.Rows(Target.Row).Interior.Color = xlNone
End If
Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

and

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A7:A4608")) Is Nothing Then
Cancel = True
Target = Format(Now, "DD MMM yyyy, ttttt")
End If
End Sub
```

The date will always insert on DoubleClick but the rows will not for the bloody life of me change colour unless I remove the bottom code completely

I also apologize in advance if I didn't paste the code correctly. If you didn't catch, I am a newbie <1 Month :)

Comment: Is there a reason you have one handler in the ThisWorkbook module and the other in the Sheet module ?

Answer (score 0):

You could combine both in one module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, _
                           ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("A7:A4608")) Is Nothing Then

        Target.Value = Format(Now, "DD MMM yyyy, ttttt")
        Cancel = True

    ElseIf Target.Column > 1 And Target.Column < 20 Then

        If Target.Interior.Color = vbWhite Then
            Sh.Rows(Target.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 162, 200)
        ElseIf Target.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 162, 200) Then
            Sh.Rows(Target.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 203)
        ElseIf Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 203) Then
            Sh.Rows(Target.Row).Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
        Cancel = True

    End If
End Sub
```